Renovate for GitLab CI/CD Components with partial semantic version
I want to use renovate to update the components referenced in my .gitlab-ci.yml file. The components are published in a strictly semantic way but I only want to refer to the components by a prefix of the version e.g., 2.4 to refer to the latest 2.4.* tag on the component. See the corresponding GitLab feature for CI/CD-Catalog Components.
What I strictly don't want is to just ignore patch-bumps. The version being proposed must strictly be on the same precision level as the one being replaced (x replaced by y, a.b by c.d etc.). I found that renovate already supports this for Docker Images.
What I've tried so far:
A:
// renovate.json
...
      "packageRules": [
      ...,
      {
            "matchFileNames": [
                ".gitlab-ci.yml"
            ],
            "groupName": "Pipeline updates",
            "semanticCommitType": "ci",
            "versioning": "docker", // <-- here
            "automerge": true
        }

Problem: This only works if there exists an exact Tag on the referenced component with a partial semantic version. E.g., the same commit has three Tags on it: 3, 3.2 and 3.2.1 and the partial Tags are being moved on release. This does not use the GitLab feature linked above and incorporates moving tags and is therefore not an acceptable solution.
B:
// renovate.json
...
      "packageRules": [
      ...,
      {
            "matchFileNames": [
                ".gitlab-ci.yml"
            ],
            "matchRepositories": [
                "to-be-continuous"
            ],
            "updateTypes": ["patch"],
            "enabled": false // <- here
        }

Problem: This just ignores updates that would introduce a patch bump. A suggested renovate-update was from 1.2 to 1.3.1 changing the version precision.
